# Image errors in openpyxl

Tags: image, python-imaging-library, openpyxl

I have a worksheet that contains two images. If I open it using openpyxl and save it, I lost the images without any error message, even if I didn't change it by code.

If I open a file without imagens and try to add it using:

```
xlsx = openpyxl.load_workbook('PlanilhaComProjetoDoUsuario.xlsx')
ws = xlsx['Identificação']

img = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image('reflorestasp.png')
img.anchor('A1')
ws.add_image(img)
```

I get the error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[17], line 1
----> 1 img = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image('reflorestasp.png')
      2 img.anchor('A1')
      3 ws.add_image(img)

File D:\temp\test\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\drawing\image.py:32, in Image.__init__(self, img)
     30 self.ref = img
     31 mark_to_close = isinstance(img, str)
---> 32 image = _import_image(img)
     33 self.width, self.height = image.size
     35 try:

File D:\temp\test\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\drawing\image.py:13, in _import_image(img)
     11 def _import_image(img):
     12     if not PILImage:
---> 13         raise ImportError('You must install Pillow to fetch image objects')
     15     if not isinstance(img, PILImage.Image):
     16         img = PILImage.open(img)

ImportError: You must install Pillow to fetch image objects
```

Pillow is already installed and I can import it in the script.

I know that those are two issues, but I think they could be connected in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd ensure all your packages are up to date first; openpyxl and pillow.

Prima facie it would appear that pillow isn't installed
If you add the line after the openpyxl import

```
print(openpyxl.drawing.image.PILImage)
```

it should return the path where the PIL package resides. If it returns False then openpyxl is not finding it.

Also I'd expect you will get an error on line

```
img.anchor('A1')
```

the correct syntax is

```
img.anchor = 'A1'
```

see openpyxl docs [openpyxl.drawing.image module](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.drawing.image.html?highlight=image#openpyxl.drawing.image.Image.anchor)

Comment: Tks! This instruction print(...) returns False, but if I can run "import PIL" or "from PIL import Image" just before "openpyxl.drawing.image.PILImage", why openpyxl can't find PIL?

Comment: The paths for your code and the paths for your imported modules may be different. Your code at location 1 may be able to find PIL but Openpyxl which would be in another location may not have the path to PIL. Were both installed the same way?

Comment: I simply create a new environment, reinstall the requirements.txt that includes PIL and openpyxl, and everything works now. Tks!